# Installing SharePoint Designer 2013 got me error "There are no products affected by this package"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I installed SharePoint Designer 2013. After 2 months it started to behave slow!
I uninstalled this program and I wanted to install again, but this error occurred:
[image]

I installed "Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 (KB2817441) 32-Bit Edition"
from microsoft, but after extracting I still get this error!

Comment: Did you try to install SharePoint Designer 2013 without Service Pack 1?

Comment: is this error while installing SharePoint designer or installing the SP1?